# What does the suffix on the NCV8402ADDR2G mean?

Tags: components, packages

This On Semiconductor part:

https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/NCV8402D-D.PDF

is described in the literature as the `NCV8402D/AD`. It doesn't describe the difference between the `D`/`AD` so far as I can tell. Also, it shows the orderable part number to be `NCV8402DDR2G` but does not describe what the `DR2G` means - SOIC package? Lead free? Tape?

I've only inferred two things:

- The first `D` after the `8402` means dual, because it's a dual driver - this is made obvious when comparing to other [drivers in the series](https://www.onsemi.com/products/discretes-drivers/protected-mosfets) such as the single `8402A`
- Only the `AD` version is in production, because the `D` version is listed as obsolete on [DigiKey](https://www.digikey.ca/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/pmic-power-distribution-switches-load-drivers/726?k=NCV8402&k=&pkeyword=NCV8402&sv=0&pv87=121326&sf=0&FV=-8%7C726%2C7%7C1%2C7%7C2&quantity=&ColumnSort=0&page=1&pageSize=25)

I'd like to nail this down so that I can properly enter it in my CAD land pattern.

Answer (score 0):

The datasheet seems to indicate that there is only one available package and so only one pinout for either part number. I would think that is all of the information you need for PCB CAD.

Comment: It's all of the information I'd technically need to go to production, but that doesn't really satisfy my curiosity.